# How to issue http-request as soon a feature is clicked in ArcGIS map-viewer

Tags: arcgis-10.5, popup, feature-layer

I'm investigating ArcGIS 10.5 web client (map viewer, not sure what to call it). I've seen information how to populate a popup menu with data merged with template, or how to add custom actions to the popup by merging data from the feature.

We're looking for a way to issue an HTTP request as soon as a feature is clicked? The request being an URL (provided in the feature details) appended with the feature-id.

But we're not intending to customize the ArcGis map viewer application on a company level, because we're just one party out of many.

So my question is; is there built-in support to customize popup actions whenever specifically our layer is displayed? Or is the customization on a per viewer-app basis.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our "Focused question / Best answer" model operates. "Is it possible?" questions aren't valued here, because the inevitable answer of "Yes" isn't going to be of much use. Please [Edit] the question to name the product you are evaluating, state the programming language you are using, and include your best effort to solve the problem in a code block within the body of the Question. You'll probably want to focus on OnClick event handling.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. i hope the edit made my question more clear.

Comment: You still haven't specified what product or language you are using, or made an attempt to use it.

Comment: i am actually new to ArgGis and their web-viewer(that's a product afaik). Are there more than one html5-map viewer by esri/arcgis?

Comment: There a number of map viewers from Esri. None of them are products *per se*. Anything coded in JavaScript can do anything web-oriented, so you're essentially asking, "Can JavaScript work from a web client?" In this respect, the question is nearly off-topic.

Comment: OK thanks. So i guess i'm looking at a customized map-viewer(arcgis web templates) hosted on an arcgis server, on a per-application basis(because of customized popup dynamics)?